# Custom formatting for pretty-printing JSON data Java

Tags: java, json, gson, minecraft, pretty-print

I'm looking for a way I can create a custom formatting "rule/s" of some sort for pretty-printing JSON data. Currently, I'm using GSON to prettyprint, however, I'd like to output in a different format. To be more specific, I am trying to match the formatting of Minecraft JSON files.

Here's an example of GSON pretty-print:

```
[
  {
    "when": {
      "OR": [
        {
          "conditional": false,
          "facing": "north"
        },
        {
          "conditional": false,
          "facing": "north"
        }
      ]
    },
    "apply": [
      {
        "model": "chain_command_block",
        "weight": 1,
        "uvlock": false,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And here's an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
[
  { "when": { "OR": [
        {"conditional": false, "facing": "north"},
        {"conditional": false, "facing": "north"}
    ]},
    "apply": [
      { "model": "chain_command_block", "weight": 1, "uvlock": false, "x": 0, "y": 0 }
    ]
  }
]
```

I think I'm going to have to manually format and output the data myself using a StringBuilder or a BufferedWriter but if anyone else has any other ideas, please let me know.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you used [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) as your JSON parser / generator library, you could write your own [`PrettyPrinter`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter.html)

Answer (score 1):

With GSON, you can register a `typeAdapter` and customise how a class should be serialised and deserialised.

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-serialization-part-1

**EDIT:** With this method, although you can define what data is used and how it's presented (in an array or a csv string etc...), I don't think you can actually change the structure of the pretty-printing.

For example, if I wanted to pretty-print an object, I also want to be able to define when to indent and when to move down to the next line for a certain class type. Still testing though so maybe I'm wrong,,,